# Why does passing function($) into jQuery(...) make the $(...) equivalent to jQuery(...)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that in a default WordPress site, for example, the dollar sign `$` isn't recognized as a pseudonym for `jQuery` and so I've always done

```
jQuery(function($) { 
   // call stuff like $(...)
} );
```

although I don't understand why it works. It's one of those things I've done as a developer without understanding why. What are the mechanics behind why it makes me able to call jQuery functions with the dollar sign within the curly braces above?

Comment: Read the documentation [Aliasing the jQuery Namespace](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual implementation of `jQuery` is more complicated, but basically you could imagine the implementation of this feature to look like:

```
function jQuery(callback) {
    callback(jQuery);
}
```

i.e. `jQuery` just passes itself to the callback.

How **you** name the parameter (`$`, `foo` or `myLittleBlueHouse`) is of no concern to `jQuery`. You could as well do:

```
jQuery(function(myLittleBlueHouse) { 
   // call stuff like myLittleBlueHouse(...)
});
```

It just seems obvious to choose `$` since jQuery itself uses that variable name as well.